# performance comparison : json vs pure html !

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm having this big dilemma for my project in terms of performance. I have a set of data in json format that need to be shown in html format. should I create the HTML version on server and send it to user or should I send json and convert it to html client-side ?

Comment: See [Which is better: HTML rendering on server or on client in JS?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349015/which-is-better-html-rendering-on-server-or-on-client-in-js).

Comment: It depends on the performance of the client and the network. Is it a lot of data that would be shown in chunks on the client side to a desktop/laptop? Is is a little bit of data that needs to be fetched often? or is it one page's worth of data that the server can generate html for really quickly, and would transfer down the wire in a reasonable size and then be viewed on a low-performance (cell phone, etc) client?

Comment: the json contains information about various types of elements for example : {"img","abc.jpg",80,60} that would be rendered, so the end result in html could be pretty big, but the json is pretty small in terms of size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

of course processing your data and preparing outputs is better done server-side, don't let all the jQuery/Ajax hype fool you...I mean it adds a lot of interactivity to your application..but if that's not needed then..let the server do it for you...after all it's one of its duties!

Answer (score 1):

If you...

1. don't care about search engine crawlers (which don't see/index content that is generated via JavaScript),
2. don't care about the users which have JavaScript turned off,
3. love JavaScript and hate server-side languages :)

... then you may choose to generate your content on the client-side.

(btw, concerning point 3, yes I know, server-side JS is becoming huge :) )